How can I convert List<SomeClass> to Map<SomeClass::getField1, Set<SomeClass::getField2>>
I have a class that has two fields as shown below
I want to convert this class into Map<SomeClass::getField1, Set<SomeClass::getField2>>
Any idea how to write a lambda for this?
I'll be grateful for any help
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public SomeClass {

  @NotBlank
  String field1;

  @NotBlank
  String field2;
}


Method references are not type parameters; they don't belong there.  Please add in to your question more details and/or examples as to what exactly you would like, and where you're going wrong.

@rgettman you're right, but I think I got what Jared was trying to say, and based my answer on that.

You need to combine Collectors.groupingBy with Collectors.mapping and Collectors.toSet:
List<SomeClass> list = List.of();
Map<String, Set<String>> map = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                SomeClass::getField1,
                Collectors.mapping(
                        SomeClass::getField2, // convert
                        Collectors.toSet()    // then collect as set
                )
        ));


Interesting.  One possible wrinkle, implied by the OP's choice of type parameters, is that he really intended it to be SomeClass<T,T>.  How does that change the answer?

@JimGarrison how do you mean? The SomeClass is given without generic type, and the result is a Map<String, Set<String>> where the keys come from SomeClass::getField1 and the set elements from SomeClass::getField2.

An alternative to using streams would be using Map.computeIfAbsent.  Which will take a key (field1) and if the value (HashSet<String>) is absent, will create and return it so the chosen field may be added to that set.
record SomeClass(String getField1, String getField2) {}

List<SomeClass> list = List.of(new SomeClass("A", "A_value1"),
         new SomeClass("B", "B_value1"), new SomeClass("A", "A_value2"),
         new SomeClass("C", "C_value1"), new SomeClass("B", "B_value2"));
 
 
Map<String, Set<String>> result = new HashMap<>();
for (SomeClass sc : list) {
    result.computeIfAbsent(sc.getField1(), v -> new HashSet<>())
            .add(sc.getField2());
}
 
result.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);

prints
A=[A_value2, A_value1]
B=[B_value2, B_value1]
C=[C_value1]

